# How to diff folders and get verbose information?

Tags: diff, hashsum

I have 2 ~55 Gb folders (with many subfolders) that contain more than 1500 files per ~30 Mb.
I need to compare them and get information if some files are missing / new files persist or their hash is not identical to original content.
How I can do it?

Comment: One way to do it is to use `rsync --dry-run` and the other settings as if you were going to backup from one of the directory tree to the other directory tree. Then `rsync` will show what it 'wants to' copy (from a 'source' to a 'target' and that indicates which files are missing or different in the target compared to the source. Another way is to use `unison` - it will show what needs to be modified and how in order to make the directory trees match (both ways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
cd path1
find . -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; >/var/tmp/sum.path1
cd path2
sha1sum -c /var/tmp/sum.path1|grep -v "OK$"
```

(the `grep` remove lines with OK at the end to display only failed missing/different hash)

And you can change the hash algorithm to try to minimize the collision factor

Comment: It works but it doesn't give information if there is new files in directory 2

Comment: @flopp, correct. One fast and dirty solution is to make the process on reverse order, first directory2